# aggrid - Filter notContains and notEqual not working on treeData

Tags: angularjs, filter, tree, ag-grid

I'm trying to fix an agGrid bug on treeData element. When I filter with contains, startsWith, endsWith, equals then it works as expected but when I filter with notContains and notEqual, nothing is filtered : parent as child elements whatever.

Have you any idea ? I looked on the Aggrid issues page but I didn't find anything.

Here is a plunkr page that presents the bug : https://embed.plnkr.co/plunk/JQV8LqyzPG039epA

Thanks for your help,